# Constructing embeddings (Lemma 2.3.3 from Marker)

Tags: logic, model-theory

Lemma 2.3.3 from Marker:

> Suppose $\mathcal N$ is an $\mathcal L_M$-structure and $\mathcal N\models \operatorname{Diag}( \mathcal M)$; then, viewing $\mathcal N$ as an $\mathcal N$-structure, there is an $\mathcal L$-embedding of $\mathcal M$ into $\mathcal N$.

First of all, I assume $\mathcal N\models \operatorname{Diag}( \mathcal M)$ means $\mathcal N\models \phi(m_1,\dots,\phi_n)$ for all $\phi(m_1,\dots,m_n)\in \operatorname{Diag}( \mathcal M)$.

I have a few question about the proof.

Define $j:M\to N$ by $m\mapsto m^\mathcal N$.

**Injectivity**. If $m_1,m_2\in M$ are distinct, then $(m_1\ne m_2) \in \operatorname{Diag}( \mathcal M)$. Why is $j(m_1)\ne j(m_2)$? Here is my conjecture: if $j(m_1)= j(m_2)$, then $m_1^\mathcal N=m_2^\mathcal N$, which is the same as $m_1=m_2$ because $m_1,m_2\in M$ and any for any $m\in M$, $m^\mathcal N=m$. But if $m_1=m_2$ in $N$, then $\mathcal N\models (m_1=m_2)$, which is not true because $\mathcal N\models \operatorname{Diag}( \mathcal M)$ and $(m_1\ne m_2)\in \operatorname{Diag}( \mathcal M)$.

Is this reasoning correct? I used the assumption that $m^\mathcal N=m$ for all $m\in M$. But why is this true? According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2950673/602716) answer, if $\mathcal M$ is an $\mathcal L$-structure and we expand $\mathcal L$ by adding constants corresp. to elts of $M$, then $m^\mathcal M=m$. But in our case I'm using that $m^\mathcal N=m$, and we don't know the relationship between $\mathcal M$ and $\mathcal N$.

**Function symbols are preserved.** Here Marker writes that if $f$ is a function symbol in $\mathcal L$ and $f^\mathcal M(m_1,\dots,m_n)=m_{n+1}$, then $f(m_1,\dots,m_n)=m_{n+1}$ is a formula in $\operatorname{Diag}( \mathcal M)$. But why so? We don't know that $f^\mathcal M$ is $f$, do we? Further, Marker says that $f^\mathcal N(j(m_1),\dots,j(m_n))=j(m_{n+1})$. If what I wrote above (namely $m^\mathcal N=m$) is true, then $j(m_i)=m_i$, but we don't know anything about $f^\mathcal N$, do we?

**Relation symbols are preserved.** Let $R$ be a relation symbol. We must show $m=(m_1,\dots,m_n)\in R^\mathcal M$ iff $(j(m_1),\dots,j(m_n))\in R^\mathcal N$. Marker says that if $m\in R^\mathcal M$ then $R(m)\in \operatorname{Diag}( \mathcal M)$ and $(j(m_1),\dots,j(m_n))\in R^\mathcal N$, without mentioning the other direction. But I can't seem to understand either direction...

Also, he doesn't say that the constant symbols are preserved, is it because constant symbols are 0-ary function symbols, and that function symbols are preserved have been verified already?

Sorry if my questions seem elementary to someone, I really have a hard time understanding all this.

Comment: If $m_1\neq m_2$ in $\mathcal{M}$, then $\mathcal{M}\models m_1\neq m_2$, so $m_1\neq m_2\in \text{Diag}(\mathcal{M})$. Here $m_1$ and $m_2$ are constant symbols. We're assuming $\mathcal{N}\models \text{Diag}(\mathcal{M})$. So $\mathcal{N}\models m_1\neq m_2$, i.e. $m_1^{\mathcal{N}}\neq m_2^{\mathcal{N}}$. Now $m_1^{\mathcal{N}}$ and $m_2^{\mathcal{N}}$ are just some arbitrary elements of $\mathcal{N}$. But the point is that $j(m_1) = m_1^{\mathcal{N}}$ and $j(m_2) = m_2^{\mathcal{N}}$ by definition of $j$. So we've shown that $j(m_1)\neq j(m_2)$.

Comment: That is, it's certainly not true that $m^{\mathcal{N}} = m$! $m$ is an element of $\mathcal{M}$, whose domain might be disjoint from the domain of $\mathcal{N}$.

Comment: If you don't mind me making a friendly suggestion: I think you might be better served by starting with a more elementary book on logic before moving to a graduate text like Marker. Maybe Enderton's *A Mathematical Introduction to Logic*? If you're really intent on diving into model theory, you could supplement your reading of Marker with *A Shorter Model Theory* by Hodges. Hodges tends to be more careful about explaining the basics. In particular, the first two chapters of Hodges go into a lot of detail about the stuff that seems to be confusing you.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thank you. I also found some lecture notes on your web page, and the page says that there are no prerequisites except algebra. Do you think your notes are suitable for my case?

Comment: You can certainly try my notes. I would say they're just as abstract as Marker's book, though, if not more so. If I was writing a textbook, I would probably be less terse.